# Cut Rounded Triangle Into 2 Equal Halves And Fill 2 Different Colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to divide a rounded triangle into 2  equal halves vertically and then fill 2 different colors in the two halves. I want to make the shape shown below in the image. Anyone please help me out with this using illustrator.

[image: I want to make this shape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a guide to mark the center line, then use a rectangle to draw over one side, select all and use Pathfinder > divide tool. Then un-group, delete extra part of rectangle, and you should have two equal parts of the triangle you can color.
[image]

Ok here is how to make the triangle and then split it.
Again start with some guides.
then draw the basic shape without any round corners.
then get your selection tool.
hold down ctrl, and click on the circles on the corners you want to round.
you will have to play with the radius you give each corner to fit your shape
then refer to the above instructions on how to split the triangle in half
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want the exact shape that I have shared in the question. Please refer that and help me with it.

Comment: This method will work no matter what shape triangle you draw. If you are unable to draw the rounded triangle in question that is completely different situation, and not a part of your question.

Comment: I tried doing it but the above method works with normal shapes(without rounded corners) but with rounded shapes when I divide it using pathfinder tool there are no rounded corners in the shape i.e. it is restored to normal shape (without rounded corners).

Comment: ok i created more directions. you can see from my demonstration that the corners remain.

Comment: Can you please mail me the ai file of the above shape that I have shared.

Comment: no I will not email you the ai file.

Comment: @JohnBurgess I don't think this method is efficient.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor That is fine, there are many ways to accomplish the same goal. Either way takes less than 30 seconds to accomplish.

Comment: I actually **never** use the Scissors tool, ever - I find it too imprecise. I'd draw a line down the middle and then align the two objects.. then Pathfinder Divide. You don't need a rectangle... a single path works great for Divide.

Comment: @Scott The method you suggested works with shapes without rounded corners. Try with shapes with rounded corners - it doesn't work i.e. the rounded corners are removed.

Comment: @JohnBurgess I tried the 2nd method you suggested but since I am using Illustrator CS6, I am unable to use Live Corners feature that you have used for rounded corners. Can you please a solution for CS6

Comment: @AnubhavSarangi did you watch my animation?? It **clearly** works fine. I created the **entire shape and split it without any issues** whatsoever. Where in my animation did I use the Rounded Corner effect??? You sure seem to be asking a lot of others without any sense of gratitude or effort on your own. This site is **not** a "tutorial on demand" site.

Answer (score 1):

Just another video of how I'd handle it from scratch....

Not necessarily better or worse than the other methods. Same general principle. However starting with a rounded rectangle offers the top curves easily. Then it's just a matter of creating the center point and curve. And with a single path you can align to the center and use `Pathfinder > Divide` easily.

[image]

Of course, if you have VectorScribe from AstuteGraphics installed, it's dead simple to get the shape from a standard triangle using the Dynamic Corners options. And I would use *far more* tool shortcuts than the video shows. I had to remember where tools are in a couple places because I'm more accustomed to their shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to use the scissors tool (<kbd>C</kbd>).

Pick the two points you want to split then click once on each with the tool. Now you have 2 equal halves. Select each in turn and join the open ends using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and color each half as desired.

Once done you can select both and group them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

[image]

Here's how to do it on a shape like the one you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want the exact shape that I have shared in the question. Please refer that and help me with it.

Comment: @AnubhavSarangi The method applies to any shape.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Please help me with drawing the shape with rounded corners. The clip shown above shows how to divide and color it  with 2 different colors but doesn't show how to draw the shape.